Eggs will not cook in shell
I steamed eggs per usual 11 minutes, ice water bath. First one: less than soft boiled. That’s funny. Tried another, same. Steamed them for another 3 minutes, no real difference. Boiled them for 4 minutes more. Still some uncooked albumen and totally runny yolks. What is going on?? They’ve now. Cooked for 18 minutes!! I’ve been cooking eggs for 60 years, some as a professional cook. Never seen this.

Are you boiling them in the same place as you did in the past 60 years?

If the eggs were refrigerated, has your fridge (or even just part of it) gotten colder lately? I know that with my fridge, if items are placed too close to one of the vents, it makes certain parts of the fridge get literally freezing cold.

@HollisHurlbut I've literally frozen eggs below a vent in the fridge before. Quite interesting to be able to peel an egg, then drop it into the water to cook.

Are you sure they are chicken eggs?   I am no expert, but I have noticed that my duck eggs have noticeably different cooking properties then my chicken eggs - particularly the albumen is thicker and cooks more consistently when frying.    (I'm not saying yours are duck eggs - indeed I imagine that is unlikely)
